# $(n-1)$-th derivative of a complex polynomial

Tags: derivatives, factorial

I cannot wrap my head around the $(n-1)$-th derivative of the polynomial $(z-2)^{n+1}$.

> $$ \frac{d^{n-1}}{dz^{n-1}}(z-2)^{n+1} = \frac{(n+1)!}{2}(z-2)^2, \quad z \in \mathbb C.$$

I get why the term $(z-2)^2$ is there, the problem is with $(n+1)!/2$. Why divide by $2$?

Comment: No!  The $n$-th derivative of a polynomial of degree $n+1$ has degree 1, not 2.  You mean the $(n-1)$-st derivative

Comment: If it is the $(n -1)$-th derivative, then the divided by 2 make sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The complex derivative works like the real one in this case:
\begin{align*}
\frac{d}{dz}(z-2)^{n+1} & =(n+1)(z-2)^n\\
(n+1)\frac{d}{dz}(z-2)^n & = (n+1)n(z-2)^{n-1} \\
& \vdots\\
(n+1)n\cdot\dots \cdot4\frac{d}{dz}(z-2)^3 & = \frac{(n+1)!}{2!}(z-2)^2 \\
\frac{(n+1)!}{2!}\frac{d}{dz}(z-2)^2 & = (n+1)!(z-2).
\end{align*}
Notice that the first derivative corresponds to having the exponent $n = (n+1)-1$ on $(z-2)$ on the right hand side of the first line. Thus at the $n$-th derivative you will have exponent $(n+1)-n=1$, meaning that the last line gives you the $n$-th derivative.

EDIT after the edit: for the $(n-1)$-th derivative just look at the line before the last.

Comment: I still don't get where the divition by 2! comes from.

Comment: Do you agree that at the $(n-2)$-th derivative the coefficient of $(z-2)^3$ is $(n+1)n\cdot \dots \cdot 4$? If yes, then you can write this as $(n+1)!/3!$. At the $(n-1)$-th derivative you get an extra factor $3$ which gives you the final factor $3(n+1)!/3\cdot 2\cdot 1 = (n+1)!/2$. Obviously $2!=2$, so it makes no difference to write $(n+1)!/2$ or $(n+1)!/2!$.